# 2d Array different column sizes

Tags: arrays, go

Lets say I want to create a two dimensional array that looks like

```
/* [
     [2],
    [3,4],
   [6,5,7],
  [4,1,8,3]
] */
```

How do can I create it using go?

Typically if I have a 2d array with equal size columns like

```
 /*   [4,1,8,1],
      [2,1,3,3],
      [7,1,4,3]
 */

matrix := make([][]int, 4)
for i := range matrix {
    matrix[i] = make([]int, 3)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create slices of different sizes at `matrix[i]`:

```
matrix := make([][]int, 4)
for i := range matrix {
    matrix[i] = make([]int, i+1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    matrix := make([][]int, 4)
    for i := range matrix {
        matrix[i] = make([]int, i+1)
    }
    fmt.Println(matrix)
}
```

Output:

```
[[0] [0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0 0]]
```

Or

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    matrix := [][]int{{2}, {3, 4}, {6, 5, 7}, {4, 1, 8, 3}}
    fmt.Println(matrix)
}
```

Output:

```
[[2] [3 4] [6 5 7] [4 1 8 3]]
```